# Retrieve the info about the ascending or descending order of a column in a grid

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, datagridview

I have a grid with a column filled with some (DateTime) dates.
The user can sort the datas by clicking on the gray arrow in the column header.
How can I retrive from the code the info if the user has chosen a descending or ascending order?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to populate Grid with Ascending order when ever user clicks on the column header perform Descending Operation.

Comment: How can I intercept if the user has clicked on the gray arrow of the column header?

Answer (score 1):

Use DataGridView Sorted Event it will be fired when click on Gray Triangle.

Ex: `dataGridView1.Sorted+=new EventHandler(dataGridView1_Sorted);`

```
private void dataGridView1_Sorted(object sender,EventArgs e)
{

}
```

please give ur Respone by putting a like in answere.